# How to use LINQ to select the object with the smaller value of the property and its value directly

Tags: c#, linq

```
var req = (from k in dc.operations.ToList()
           group k by k.id_employee into g
           select new { id_emp = g.Key , nbr = g.Count(),  }
          ).Take(1).SingleOrDefault();

double mint=0;
for (int i = 0; i < req.nbr; i++)
{
    var r = (from l in dc.operations
             where l.id_employee == req.id_emp
             select l).Take(1).ToList();
    var r2 = (from l in dc.operations
             where l.id_employee == req.id_emp
             && l.date_operation.Value > r[i].date_operation.Value
             select l).Take(1).ToList();
    double nbr_minut = (r[i].date_operation.Value - r2[i].date_operation.Value).TotalMinutes;
    mint = +nbr_minut;
    nbr_minut = 0;
}

TimeSpan span = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(mint);
string nbr_houre = span.ToString(@"hh\:mm");

label1.Text = nbr_houre.ToString();
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code posted, and what is the expected instead?

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the question, lets say you have a list of Person and you want to get the youngest person and his age.
You can do this:

```
people.OrderBy(p => p.Age).Select(p => new {Dude = p, Age = p.Age}).FirstOrDefault();
```